# Running jira behind an apache: what is the proxyName configuration for?

Tags: jira

from the documentation it seems that I have to edit the server.xml file to set: proxyName, proxyPort, scheme.

Not only doesn't it explain what those settings are for, but I also can't find any motivation behind it. Doesn't the usual apache reverse proxy configuration just suffices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific parameters you refer to in `server.xml` file are [Tomcat `<Connector>` attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html).

The practical impact is that Jira or third-party apps will sometimes use these attributes to construct fully-qualified URLs to refer back to Jira, and which also sometimes get passed on to the client browser. The attributes configured here should match the base URL configured in the main Jira system configuration.

For example, Jira may send redirects to the user's browser if it detects that you are accessing Jira from something other than the canonical URL as configured here. It will also occasionally construct fully-qualified URLs (rather than relative URLs) in certain parts of the application.

You also generally need to have correct values set for these attributes (as well as the base URL) if you want Application Links and the UPM (app manager) to work correctly.

For local testing or development purposes, it is generally acceptable to remove these attributes entirely (it will stop auto-redirection from happening), so long as you're always accessing Jira from the base URL, and knowing that you may have issues with AppLinks or the UPM. Removing them is certainly better than having an incorrectly-configured `proxyName`, which would otherwise generate redirects to the wrong place.